# regex to target .min.js. extensions in file url

Tags: javascript, regex, minify

min.js files in a wordpress site and my caching plugin says "Enter the URL of JS files to reject (one per line).
You can use regular expressions (regex)."

Is there a way too put in a url with regex and target all files that have .min.js in them so I can exclude them all at once?

The same is also for .min.css files.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you are looking for looks like this:

```
^.+\.min\.(js|css)$
```

The explanation from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pQ9wN3/1). I'll just past it here, since I can't do a better job:

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `.+` matches any character (except newline)

  - Quantifier: `+` Between one and
    unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
    [greedy]
- `\.` matches the character . literally
- `min` matches the
  characters min literally (case sensitive)
- `\.` matches the character .
  literally
- 1st Capturing group `(js|css)`

  - 1st Alternative: `js` js matches
    the characters js literally (case sensitive)
  - 2nd Alternative: `css` css
    matches the characters css literally (case sensitive)
- `$` assert
  position at end of the string